# Travelport uAPI ticketing

Tags: xml, soap, travelport-api

I'm getting following error when I request to ticket

> "Host error during ticket issue. INVALID ND LINKAGE"

Request I've sent is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <air:AirTicketingReq xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v35_0" AuthorizedBy="Travelport" BulkTicket="false" ReturnInfoOnFail="true" TargetBranch="P7038833" TraceId="trace">
        <com:BillingPointOfSaleInfo xmlns:com="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v35_0" OriginApplication="UAPI"/>
        <air:AirReservationLocatorCode>K8H3JM</air:AirReservationLocatorCode>
    </air:AirTicketingReq>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Am I supposed to include any additional information?

Comment: Hello n3xus, i am getting the same issue today, can you please tell me how your issue was resolved ?

Comment: @BhoopeshPathak You have to ask support from TravelPort. It turns out they configure your credential to print tickets. There is nothing you can do on your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact the account manager: "Please contact your Travelport Account Manager to ask for trial credentials with ticketing provisioned on it."

https://github.com/Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial/issues/118